# alguna forma de validar tres variables juntas en JS?

Tags: php, javascript, base-de-datos, vue.js, validación

Estoy tratando de validar un formulario, para eso tengo que validar tres inputs que serian el lot, la cantidad de empaque y la cantidad de cajas, si los tres son correctos se ingresa a la base de datos, como puedo hacer para ir validando una a una? y si alguna tiene error retornar, pensaba en una funcion y hacer un ciclo for de 0 a 3 ya que son solo tres variables y si hay un error esta se sale del ciclo, pero hay alguna manera mas elegante?

cabe recalcar que tengo dos expresiones regulares, una para cantidad y cajas y la otra para lot

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un [mcve]? Será más fácil ayudarte si tenemos algo con lo que hacer pruebas. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente hacer un `if` con tres condiciones sea la solución más lógica en tu caso, pero si tienes varios formularios podría venirte bien parametrizar la validación. Las reglas de validación podrían venir del servidor (donde tienes que validar de todos modos) con lo que finalmente evitarías errores de validación y duplicación de código.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var input_vals = {
  set1: {
    amount: '133',
    boxes: '8',
    lot: 'L422'
  },
  set2: {
    amount: '133',
    boxes: 'L8',
    lot: 'L422'
  }
};

var validation_regex = {
  rule1: /^\d+$/,
  rule2: /^L\d+/
};

var validation_rules = [
  { name: 'amount', regex: validation_regex.rule1 },
  { name: 'boxes',  regex: validation_regex.rule1 },
  { name: 'lot',    regex: validation_regex.rule2 }
];

for (var setn in input_vals) {

  var validation_result = validate_input(input_vals[setn], validation_rules);

  if (validation_result.is_valid) {
      console.log(setn + ": ALL OK");
  } else {
      console.log(setn + ": Invalid value for " + validation_result.invalid_value);
  }
  
}

function validate_input(vals, rules)
{
  var invalid_rule = rules.find(function(rule) {
    return !vals[rule.name].match(rule.regex);
  });

  return {
    is_valid: !invalid_rule,
    invalid_value: invalid_rule && invalid_rule.name
  };
}
</script>
```

Haciendo los cambios necesarios en `validate_input()`, en el hash `validation_rules` podrías tener expresiones regulares en el campo `name`, definir una función de validación en vez (o además) de una expresión regular, etc.

Pero como digo, en tu caso de un formulario con 3 valores, sin más contexto, yo usaría un `if` y ya está.